# How to React Player fit in div box?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-player

How to React Player fit in div box?
My code is like this but the React Video doesn't fit  box like photo

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[image]

Top.js

```
{camera.map((item,i) => 
  <div key={i} className="discover_device col-4">
    <div className="box_dicover_camera">
    <Link className="box_dicover_camera_link" to={`/camera_detail_condo/${item.entity_id}`}>

    <ReactPlayer
      className="camera_video_discover"
      url={'xxx.com'}
      controls={false}
      playing
      muted
      config={{
        file: {
          hlsOptions: {
            xhrSetup: (xhr) => {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`);
            },
          },
        },
      }} />
    </Link>
    <div className="discover_item_room_name_entity_id">
      <p className="discover_item_room_name_carmera">{item.room_name}</p>
      <p className="discover_item_entity_id_camera">{item.entity_id}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

App.css

```
.box_dicover_camera {
  position: relative;
  background:#1E3E75; 
  padding:15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box_dicover_camera .camera_video_discover {
  object-fit: cover !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.camera_video_discover video {
  position: relative !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

I want to fit the video in box_dicover_camera.
The ideal one is the following photo.
The video fulfills the box_dicover_camera.
(I hide the video with red square so just ignore it)
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproductible example. And please clarify what exactly you want the screen to look like. Do you want your temperature and garage box to fix in a 6 cells grid ?

Comment: Thank you. I add what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is correct

```
.camera_video_discover video {
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  transform: none !important;
  width: 340px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
<div className="box_dicover_camera">
  <ReactPlayer
      className="camera_video_discover"/>
</div>
```

```css
.box_dicover_camera {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box_dicover_camera .camera_video_discover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Note that if you want the video to fit the entire blue area, it will need to have a corresponding ratio (width/height being the same as 340/300 of blue square).